# assigning a GameObject to a 2D array of GameObjects return null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, null, instantiation

I have a 2D array of GameObjects, and I want to assign a GameObject from 2 for loops, but the assignment returns null.

```
    void PlaceBricks(){
    placedBricksPositions=new GameObject[columnNumber*2,rowNumber*2]; //doubled the size just to make sure it fits
    FixBorders();
    List<GameObject> bricksWithRates=GetBrickWithRatesList();

    int xCounter=0;

    for(float x=topRight.x;x>=bottomLeft.x;x-=(topRight.x-bottomLeft.x)/columnNumber){
        int yCounter=0;Debug.Log("hola");
        for(float y=topRight.y;y>=bottomLeft.y;y-=(topRight.y-bottomLeft.y)/rowNumber){
            placedBricksPositions[xCounter,yCounter++]=Instantiate(
                GetBrickToSpawn(bricksWithRates),new Vector3(x,y,0),Quaternion.identity);
            
            Debug.Log(placedBricksPositions[xCounter,yCounter]);
        }
        xCounter++;
    }
}
```

the gameobjects are being instantiated normally, and assigning it to a normal gameobject works, but when assigning that gameobject to the array it also returns null.

Comment: are you sure? are you sure that its not assigning it to ycounter, then adding 1, so sure ycounter+1 is null but ycounter the original gets an object?

Comment: @BugFinder yep it was right, figured that later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i incremented yCounter then debugged using it, while it wasn't assigned yet, so it was a debug problem